# 18.04 boot doesn't recognize 16.04 USB

Tags: boot, grub-efi

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro with Ubuntu 18.04 on it. I can't access the GUI on startup. The error says `brcmf_inetaddr_changed: fail to get arp ip table`. But I can access a bash session after logging in on the command line.

On a separate Windows 10 machine, I made a 16.04 USB drive with the Unetbootin application. Trying to boot the MBP from this with the option key, I can see the boot menu and login to my wifi network, but there's only one option for me to select - EFI Boot. Selecting it, I end up with the same `brcmf` error. If I hold down escape on startup (with the USB plugged in), I get to a Grub shell, but I haven't found this productive since it somehow doesn't recognize the `root` command

Any advice how I can install 16.04 on my slightly broken 18.04 machine?

Comment: What does "MBP" mean?

Comment: @Elias MacBook Pro